# How do I provide an incrementing counter in place of an existing JSON value using jq

Tags: loops, jq

I have an JSON file similar to this:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "stage" : {
        "objects" : [
            {
                "foo" : 1100,
                "bar" : false,
                "id" : "56a983f1-8111-4abc-a1eb-263d41cfb098"
            },
            {
                "foo" : 1100,
                "bar" : false,
                "id" : "6369df4b-90c4-4695-8a9c-6bb2b8da5976"
            }],
        "bish" : "#FFFFFF"
    },
    "more": "abcd"
}
```

I would like the output to be exactly the same, with the exception of an incrementing integer in place of the "id" : "guid" - something like:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "stage" : {
        "objects" : [
            {
                "foo" : 1100,
                "bar" : false,
                "id" : 1
            },
            {
                "foo" : 1100,
                "bar" : false,
                "id" : 2
            }],
        "bish" : "#FFFFFF"
    },
    "more": "abcd"
}
```

I'm new to jq.  I can set the id's to a fixed integer with .stage.objects[].id |= 1.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "stage": {
    "objects": [
      {
        "foo": 1100,
        "bar": false,
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "foo": 1100,
        "bar": false,
        "id": 1
      }
    ],
    "bish": "#FFFFFF"
  },
  "more": "abcd"
}
```

I can't figure out the syntax to make the assigned number iterate.

I tried various combinations of map, reduce, to_entries, foreach and other strategies mentioned in answers to similar questions but the data in those examples always consisted of something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a variant using `reduce` to iterate over the `keys`:

```bash
.stage.objects |= reduce keys[] as $i (.; .[$i].id = $i + 1)
```

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "stage": {
    "objects": [
      {
        "foo": 1100,
        "bar": false,
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "foo": 1100,
        "bar": false,
        "id": 2
      }
    ],
    "bish": "#FFFFFF"
  },
  "more": "abcd"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JOl_jd4Caye)

---

##### Update:

> Is there a way to make the search and replace go deep? If the items in the objects array had children arrays with id's, could they be replaced as well?

Of course. You could enhance the LHS of the update to also cover all `.children` arrays recursively using `recurse(.[].children | arrays)`:

```bash
(.stage.objects | recurse(.[].children | arrays)) |=
  reduce keys[] as $i (.; .[$i].id = $i + 1)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YV4-cHh4hTm)

Note that in this case each `.children` array is treated independently, thus numbering starts from `1` in each of them. If you want a continuous numbering instead, it has to be done outside and brought down into the iteration. Here's a solution gathering the target paths using `path`, numbering them using `to_entries`, and setting them iteratively using `setpath`:

```bash
reduce (
  [path(.stage.objects[] | recurse(.children | arrays[]).id)] | to_entries[]
) as $i (.; setpath($i.value; $i.key + 1))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/M1gw2A3bx2h)

Comment: Is there a way to make the search and replace go deep?  If the items in the objects array had children arrays with id's, could they be replaced as well? 
'' { "foo": 1100, "bar": false, "id": "56a983f1-8111-4abc-a1eb-263d41cfb098", "children": [ { id: "2453da65-b549-4760-ad71-be40e64d5c73"}]
''
What if sometimes the "children" array was empty?  "children":[]

Comment: @aspen In the recursive case, do you want a consecutive numbering of all items, or should each level start again counting from `1`?

Comment: your second version was spot on with the index outside so that each id has a unique integer.  This is incredibly powerful stuff, thanks everyone who answered so much for the help!  It's going to take me a lot of practice to really grok this.

Comment: @aspen please don't move goalposts. Don't ask a question, have it answered, then have the answer changed to answer something not in the initial question. This makes the answer not an answer to the question and all other answers useless.

Comment: @knittl - your answer is still a great answer to the main question and I thank you for it - I imagine for most people your answer will suit their use-case.  Extending the technique of finding the "id" to go deep didn't seem worthy of creating a completely new question as it is a refinement of the original question rather than a new idea.  Still, I am new to using forums, so next time I will try and think of all the possible things I might want to know and put them in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit the fact that `to_entries` on arrays uses the index as "key", then modify your value:

```
.stage.objects |= (to_entries | map(.value.id = .key + 1 | .value))
```

or

```
.stage.objects |= (to_entries | map(.value += {id: (.key + 1)} | .value))
```

Output:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "stage": {
    "objects": [
      {
        "foo": 1100,
        "bar": false,
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "foo": 1100,
        "bar": false,
        "id": 2
      }
    ],
    "bish": "#FFFFFF"
  },
  "more": "abcd"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @knittl, your answer works perfectly. I shall study it more to try to understand properly how it works.

Comment: [Demo on jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/9dXjEyGGZ0m)